# The subsequent Job is not able to read the output of the previous job immediately

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have two sequencial Job1, and Job2. The output of Job1 is written into HDFS. Job2 will download the output of Job1 to the local file system. However, I found that the sizes of the files is 0 after the download. It is because when Job2 starts to download, the output of Job1 is still not written into the HDFS.

To solve this problem, now I have to wait a while after finishing Job1, e.g., about 30 seconds , which let the output of Job1 fully persists to HDFS. Then, I run the Job2.

Could anybody know how to solve this problem? That is, let Job2 not have to wait.
it seems like the Chain Job problem. I think it should have the way for this problem.

Comment: I am not sure but this might be due the buffered data not written to the disk. This is some thing interesting. Post a query to `hdfs-dev@hadoop.apache.org` for some response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it necessary for Job 2 to download the files to local file system? Can't your job work off the files in HDFS?
2. Are you doing it this way?

   ```
   Job job1 = new Job(conf, "Job1");
   //configure job properties
   job.waitForCompletion(true);

   if (job.isSuccessful()) {
       Job job2 = new Job(conf2, "job2");
       //and so on
   }`
   ```

Does this help?